# Find max subset of a huge set of integers

Tags: algorithm, set, subset, max-size

I have a huge set (S) of long unsigned integers in a .txt file. How can I find the max subset (Pmax) of S  with the following property:

```
P{X1,X2,X3,...,Xn) | X1>=(Xn/4)
```

More details:

1. When I say max subset I mean the subset with the greatest number of elements(n->max).
2. I can't load .txt into an array because of limited memory.
3. My system memory is 200MB
4. txt file has 10^6 integers. Each integer can be long unsigned 32bit.
5. I need to find the biggest subset of S with the condition:

X1 < X2 < X3 < ... < Xn-1 < Xn such as X1 >= (XN/4)

For example if the txt file has the following:
15,14,13,4,2,2,3,10,1,2,2 
then these are the possible subsets:

P1(4,10,13,14,15)

P2(3,4,10)

P3(1,2,2,2,2,3,4)

so Pmax(1,2,2,2,2,3,4) because it has more elements.

In fact I don't want to find exactly which is the Pmax. I just want to find the number of elements of the subset Pmax. So here it is 7.

The algorithm should be really fast.

I don't look for someone to do my work. I just need a corresponding problem so I can look for the efficient solution. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Your _memory_ is 200MB? Or your file? Also, what is `P`? And by `|` do you mean "such that"?

Comment: And as a side note, in this website we try to help you, not do your work. You need to at least show some effort. What have you tried already? What have you found by searching on google and why weren't what you have found good enough for your purpose?

Comment: I might misunderstand the way you wrote down the condition, but don't you mean to write that all numbers in the subset are larger than X1? The way you wrote it now the max subset is almost the entire file by definition.

Comment: So in the array `[1,3,12,16,20,99]`, the answer would be `[12,1,2]`? Because 12>(16/4) and 12>(20/4), but 12<(99/4)?

Comment: First of all I never asked anyone to do my work. I just need a corresponding problem so I can find my solution.

Comment: 1) My system memory is 200MB
2).txt files has 10^6 long unsigned integers.
2) I need to find the biggest subset of S with the condition:
X1<X2<X3...<Xn such as X1>XN/4
For example if the txt file has the following:
15,14,13,4,2,2,3,10,1,2,2 then these are the possible subsets:
P1={4,10,13,14,15}
P2={3,4,10}
P3={1,2,2,2,2,3,4}
so
Pmax=P3={1,2,2,2,2,3,4} because it has more elements.
In fact I don't want to find exactly which is the Pmax. I just want to find the number of elements of the subset Pmax. So here it is 7.

Comment: @chrisk. I belive you meant non strict versions of comparison operators (<= >= not < and >)

Comment: yes I corrected it. X1 >= (XN/4) not X1 > (XN/4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is:

1. Sort the list first (Complexity O(nlogn)
2. With a moving window, find the largest acceptable window. (Complexity O(n))

Complexity: O(nlogn).

More details about step2:

Let low keep track of the lowest element and high the highest element.

Initialization: Set low to the first element. Do a binary search for 4*x[low], and that is your high location. Set maxWindow=high-low+1.

At every step: Increment high by 1, and increment low such that x[low]>=x[high]. Calculate number of elements = high-low+1, and update maxWindow accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
But how can I sort the data in the txt file since I can't load it to a list or an array? Wouldn't it be very slow to sort it within the txt file?

Comment: @chrisk. There are many constant memory sorting algorithm (Eg. MergeSort). You can either use that or use the command line sort function in linux. In any case this can be done in O(nlogn) time. Is this a real problem or a interview/test problem?

Comment: thanks. this is not a real problem. it is a test problem so I can't presort the txt file...

Comment: You can that you **will** use any of the constant memory merge sort to achieve the sort. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Optimizing_merge_sort

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your condition means "where all elements in the subset are larger than X1 divided by 4" you'd need 2 simple nested loops and some helper variables.

In pseudocode something like this should work:

```
var idx = 0, largest = 0, currentIdx = 0;

while(var current = getIntegerFromFileById(currentIdx))
{
  var size = 1;
  while(getIntegerFromFileById(currentIdx + size++) > current / 4);
  if(size > largest) {
    idx = currentIdx;
    largest = size;
  }
  currentIdx++;
}
print "Longest subset is at index {idx}.";
print "It contains {largest} consecutive elements.";
```

This is also the de facto optimal implementation. The most obvious optimization would be to load the integers progressively in an in-memory buffer during the scan to prevent double I/O operations.

In case I misunderstood the condition this should still be easily adaptable to most other conditions, the surrounding algorithm stays the same, you just modify the condition in the inner while.

Comment: The complexity is O(n^2). You can do better. See below.

Comment: I posted my solution before several clarifications about the conditions. For the condition I was assuming the TS meant this is the optimal solution since it was not clear the elements didn't have to be in order (as such excluding presorting from options, also that isn't possible within the general constraints).

Comment: sorry I didn't make the problem clear. I really appreciate your help. Thanks